# Can I display a page's social network activity without asking for user permissions?

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus, pinterest

I was wondering if it was possible to display who liked, shared, +1d, tweeted, etc a page in my site without having extended permissions? I was thinking on something like this http://awesomescreenshot.com/00b58w7eb

I know I can get the total from most of the social networks api but I'm not sure about the user-specific data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Getting who tweeted via the Twitter API is easy. Most tweets are public as are most profiles.

On Facebook, you *should* be able to get that by querying [stream_tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_tag/) as your page.

I've tried to do something similar and I can't get it to return any data for a page (but I can for a user.) Even if you could get it to work, Facebook's restrictions on stream objects (50 items or 30 days worth of info, whichever is fewer, including posts that will not be returned by your query because of privacy settings) makes a query like this much harder to deal with.

I haven't delved into the Google or Pinterest API to see how difficult they are.

Answer (score 0):

I can help with the Google+ part :)

Given a URL there's no Google+ API that will tell you all of the reshares, comments and +1's. However, if you do manage to identify an activity that is associated with your URL you can use the REST API's [comments.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/comments/list) and [people.listByActivity](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/listByActivity) methods to find these details.

If you're not interested in programatic access to this data and would instead just like some dashboarding you may be interested in the Google Analytics [social tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial).  It uses the callbacks from various sharing buttons to track social activity.